# Validación de fields en Xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estoy validando ciertos campos en Xamarin pero estoy teniendo problemas con los que el valor se obtiene como un entero o valor de lista. Con el "String id" no tengo ningún problema pero con los demás si, y creo que es por tema de casteos... La condición "IsNullOrEmpty" se cumple perfectamente si dejo el valor vacío en el ID, en las demás se la salta directamente y guarda los datos...

Si alguien me pudiese iluminar....

```
public void evento_click(object sender, EventArgs a)
{
    string id = txtMat.Text;
    // int comb = pckComb.SelectedIndex;
    // Usuario idu = lsvuser.SelectedItem as Usuario;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ||String.IsNullOrEmpty(pckComb.SelectedIndex.ToString())|| String.IsNullOrEmpty(lsvuser.SelectedItem.ToString()) ) 
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", "Ha introducido un campo incorrecto", "Volver");
    }
    else
    {
        int comb = pckComb.SelectedIndex;
        Usuario idu = lsvuser.SelectedItem as Usuario;

        if (ID == String.Empty)
        { 
            App.AzureService.Guardar(id, comb,idu.Id);
            DisplayAlert("Aviso", "almacenado correctamente", "Volver");
        }
        else
            App.AzureService.ModificarVehiculo(id, comb,idu.Id);

        Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que es `ID`? de donde viene?

Comment: string id = txtMat.Text; //Es un campo de texto

Comment: No es lo mismo `id` que `ID`. De todas maneras,imagino que el problema lo tienes en el primer `if`,es asi?

Comment: Si amigo, el problema lo tengo en el primer IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a analizar tu `if` por partes:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id)
```

Aqui ningun problema,ya que `id` es un `string`.

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(pckComb.SelectedIndex.ToString())
```

Aqui tienes tu primer error. `pckComb.SelectedIndex` siempre va a tener algun valor (aunque sea -1 en el caso de que no haya nada seleccionado). Con lo que al convertirlo a string,si no hay nada seleccionado, tendrás `"-1"`, lo que obviamente no es `null` ni empty. Si lo que intentas es controlar que tengas un elemento seleccionado en ese control, lo que debes hacer es algo como:

```
pckComb.SelectedIndex==-1 // no hay ningun elemento seleccionado
```

Vamos con la tercera condición:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(lsvuser.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

Si `lsvuser.SelectedItem` es null, esta condición te lanzará una `NullReferenceException`. En cualquier otro caso, la condición nunca va a cumplirse ya que `SelectedItem` contiene un objeto, y al aplicarle `ToString` probablemente te devuelva el **nombre de la clase del objeto** ( a no ser que este sea un `string`), con lo que tampoco es `null` ni esta vacio. 
Al tratarse de un `ListView`, si lo que quieres comprobar es que exista un item seleccionado,debes comprobar que `SelectedItem` no sea `null`:

```
lsvuser.SelectedItem==null
```

Con lo que la cosa debería quedar mas o menos asi:

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id) ||
    pckComb.SelectedIndex==-1 ||
    lsvuser.SelectedItem==null)
{
    DisplayAlert("Error", "Ha introducido un campo incorrecto", "Volver");
}
```

Espero haberte aclarado tus dudas.

Comment: Muy buena respuesta Pikoh....funciona genial !! pero la propiedad "SelectedIndex" para el listview (lsvuser) no me aparece...Si deseas puedo poner todas las propiedades que puedo aplicarle. Pero de selección solo puedo ponerle SelectedItem o ItemSelected.... Saludos

Comment: Vale,no soy experto en Xamarin, pero para el listview imagino que debes comprobar si `SelectedItem` es null: `lsvuser.SelectedItem==null` He editado la respuesta

Comment: Lo he probado y parece ser que funciona bien. Muchisimas gracias Pikoh. Tengo ahora otras dudas relacionadas con validaciones pero no sé si formular otro nuevo hilo o preguntarlo aqui en los comentarios. Saludos

Comment: Creo que es mejor que lances una nueva pregunta, ya que esta ya está respondida :)